# Real time changing status of a point, web mapping

Tags: leaflet, web-mapping

I’m new to web mapping and developing and I try to make a web map with points. The points are bank ATMs. The points will change color depending on their condition. There will be three different colors and conditions. The condition and the color of a point will change in real time. I'll use the Leaflet For Web <strike>platform</strike> map software.

<strike>Do I need a database and if yes</strike> how to connect a point with a database. Is any plugin for changing the status in real time?

**Edit:**
Web platform = Web map software
The data will be in a database. The data that relate with the status of each point not the Lat Lon information.

Comment: Where is the data stored? Which format is it in? How is it updated?

Comment: Are you allowed to work with GeoJSON?, see [Leaflet Realtime](https://github.com/perliedman/leaflet-realtime).

Comment: Yes I can use GeoJson

Comment: Could you give us a sample of the source data? (e.g. lines of a csv, etc.)

Comment: It's generally unwise to split the geometry from attributes, at least where rendering is concerned. This is especially true where attributed symbology is required.

Answer (score 1):

A Google search for "leaflet realtime" has yielded a perfect leaflet plugin for your needs:

https://github.com/perliedman/leaflet-realtime boasts: "Put realtime data on a Leaflet map: live tracking GPS units, sensor data or just about anything."

You will need to either expose an HTTP endpoint at which the plugin can pull new data or  push data by more complicated means. Those are different tasks though and probably more suited for StackOverflow if you need help.